# Clear stdin of a string/array in c

Tags: c, scanf

Ok, I think that I am going a bit crazy here, I tried many solutions but none work, fflush is one of them.
I just want to clear the stdin.

```
struct j{
char name[9]
}
typedef j j_t;
j_t array[5];
int num=0;
printf("enter the string");
scanf("%8s", array[x].name);
----what do I put here to clean stdin?---
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: What are we supposed to understand from that single line of code? Is it something you tried that doesn't work? Is it something you want to print the result of? Please give  complete code as a [mre] and provide the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: You can’t clear stdin; the best you can do is read whatever content is available on stdin and don’t do anything with it.

Comment: To clear `stdin` (extract/discard characters), You can use a simple `int c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) { c = getchar(); }` or written as a `for` loop `for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}`. You can wrap either in a convenient function `void empty_stdin (void) { /* put choice here */ }` You call `empty_stdin();` whenever unread characters remain that you want to remove. If you call `empty_stdin()` when there are no characters in `stdin`, `getchar()` will block (sit doing nothing) waiting on input.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct j{
char name[9]
}
typedef j j_t;
j_t array[5];
int num=0;
printf("enter the string");
scanf("%8s", array[x].name);
scanf("%*s");
```

The character `*` means to ignore the text read, so read one more line but ignore it may answer your question.